# JsonConvert, JObject, JProperty

Tags: c#, json

I have the following code that creates NewtonSoft Jobjects

```
JObject o = new JObject(new JProperty("DataSources", new JArray(from p in repDatasource.DataSources select JObject( JProperty("Columns", new JArray (from q in p.columns select new JObject(new JProperty("Name", q.Name),new JProperty("Type", q.Type))))))));
```

that produces a Json object like this. The DataSources and columns are actually Jarrays

```
{
    "DataSources": [{
        "Columns": [{
            "Name": "OSHYPROJECT__ProjectStatus",
            "Type": "System.String"
        }, {
            "Name": "OSHYPROJECT__Pic",
            "Type": "System.String"
        }]
    }, {
        "Columns": [{
            "Name": "Complaint__Brand",
            "Type": "System.Int32"
        }, {
            "Name": "Complaint__Group",
            "Type": "System.Int32"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to get a Json that instead of arrays is creating something like this (see that instead of arrays,  there exist indexes)

```
"DataSources": {
            "0": {
                "Columns": {
                    "0": {
                        "Name": "CategoryID",
                        "Type": "System.String"
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "Name": "CategoryName",
                        "Type": "System.String"
                    }
                },
                "NameInSource": "Dk"
            },
            "1": {
                "Ident": "StiDataTableSource",
                "Columns": {
                    "0": {
                        "Name": "pColumn1",
                        "Type": "System.String"
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "Name": "pColumn2",
                        "Type": "System.String"
                    }
                },
                "NameInSource": "Dk"
            }
        }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You need to create a dictionary with an `int` as the key and then serialize that.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on here? This is a simple translation. Loop the objects and transform them as you see fit

Comment: I believe that Matt Burland's answer is the correct one. I just needed a Dictionary instead of a list

Comment: Without more detail on what your source looks like it's hard to give anything more than a very general answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dictionary (with an `int` key) instead of a list or array. Then you can serialize it to json with the structure you want.

In very general terms, you could do something like this (assuming `dataSources` is a list):

```
var myDictionary = dataSources.Select((o,idx) => new { o, idx })
                              .ToDictionary(k => k.idx, v => v.o);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDictionary);
```

Of course, your code will be a little bit more complicated because you need to convert both the `DataSource` and the `Columns` within, but the principle is the same.

I'll also add that it's much easier to create a regular .NET object and then serialize it than to muck about with `JObject` and `JArray` directly. Those objects are low level and you shouldn't really need to mess with them unless you need some very particular handling of serialization.